# How to handle a question that isn't a question, but still helpful?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, not-a-real-question

I just found a question that isn't a question, but the intention is good.

[IPhone EventKit Discrepancy with NSDate ( Time is off by 1 hour )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603702/iphone-eventkit-discrepancy-with-nsdate-time-is-off-by-1-hour)

It's not a real question, not a question at all actually, but it might still be helpful to someone.

It could easily be rewritten as a question and one could extract the answer and post it as an answer. That way it would be a real question and probably more helpful than before.

What is the correct way to handle this situation?

Comment: Ask the OP to edit it to be a question, answer it, and accept the answer?

Comment: (1) If it's helpful, why have you not up-voted it? ;) ... (2) In addition to Soumya92's suggestion, you can also edit their question -- which I have done in this case, as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [the example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603702/iphone-eventkit-discrepancy-with-nsdate-time-is-off-by-1-hour), this approach worked just fine:

1. Edit the question, separating out the question from the answer.  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6603702/revisions).
2. Optionally, post a helpful comment [like jtbandes did](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6603702/331508).
3. The OP very quickly learned and [did post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603702/iphone-eventkit-discrepancy-with-nsdate-time-is-off-by-1-hour/6618301#6618301).  The question soon was in a "proper" Q&A format.